# How to filter out selected tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tables with following names:

```
PID_01
PID_02
PID_03
...

PID_LIST_01
PID_LIST_02
PID_LIST_03
...
```

Need to perform the following query

```
SELECT
  Column01,
  Column02,
  Column03
FROM
  `dataset.PID_*`
```

only on

```
PID_01
PID_02
PID_03
...
```

How to filter out the unneeded tables?

Comment: can you please first take care of your previous questions  - so we feel that our answers are actually helping :o)

Comment: just did it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PID_` and `PID_LIST_` tables have the same schema or at least both have those three columns, below should work

```sql
SELECT
  Column01,
  Column02,
  Column03
FROM
  `dataset.PID_*`
WHERE NOT _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'LIST_%'
```

there can be variations of above WHERE clause - but I hope you got an idea

Comment: _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'LIST_%' is not working for PID_LIST_01 - LIST is in the middle. Probably need to use SUBSTR but how?

Comment: for `PID_LIST_01` the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is `LIST_01` so `LIKE 'LIST_%'` sure works - please verify that you properly use the code from my answer

Comment: Got a message "Wildcard table over non partitioning tables and field based partitioning tables is not yet supported, first normal table my-dev:dataset.PID_LIST_01, first column table topinvestor-app-dev:US_DATA.PID_01" - does not filter them out

Comment: See the first sentence in my answer. looks like your tables have different schema :o(

Comment: Yes - different, but common sense tells we talk about table names - why BigQuery is made like this?

Comment: also, somehow it looks like those tables are even in different datasets - its a little confusing - you might want to provide more details / accurate ones so we can further look into your issue

Comment: They are on same dataset

Comment: To eliminate any name conflicts I just generated the tables again with different name structure. Now it works fine.

Comment: You have been very helpful. Thank you.